# How can i create placeholders in NuSpec file and Replace them via TeamCity parameters

Tags: c#, teamcity, nuget-package

I am trying to create PlaceHolders in Nuspec and Replace them via TeamCity parameters, but teamcity does not recognise them.
Here is my NuSpec files Metadata

```
<metadata>
    <id>Id.@environment@</id>
    <title>Title.@environment@</title>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Charles Taylor</authors>
    <owners>Charles Taylor</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://www.ctcplc.com</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://www.ctcplc.com</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Currency Request</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
</metadata>
```

I have an environment variable in TeamCity. Team City crashes during build that i can't recognise these values.

I have tried changing @ to $, but no luck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some replacement tokens in a NuSpec file are pulled from the assembly at the point of packaging it.

In order to provide additional token values to be substituted, you can use the `-Properties` switch, but you must be using the **$token$** syntax in your NuSpec file, and not @token@

e.g.

```
nuget pack -Properties "Environment=DEV;Something=Else"
```

More details can be found here - [NuSpec documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#replacement-tokens)

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

If you add a NuGet Pack build step and how the advanced options, you should be presented with an input field to enter the properties in TeamCity

[image]

Or you can make use of the command line parameters field and enter them there in using the syntax `-Properties "Environment=DEV;Something=Else"`

Comment: Many thanks for answering. How can i use Properties switch in TeamCity?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for that.